# TOS and privacy policy don't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Jobs bug.

Popup for "asking a question" the links for privacy policy and tos don't work.

[image]

Clicking either link simply closes the dialog - Please fix!

Comment: If anything, those links are also plain http, so if a dev goes fixing whatever is causing that bug, they might want to change the protocol to https as well.

Comment: I'm doing both :)

Comment: @g3rv4 - Shouldn't they open in a new window / tab?  Just thinking out loud here...

Comment: @JonH wasn't the, inconsistent applied, rule on SE sites that links open in the same window? If the user doesn't want that, they should use whatever feature their browser offer to open a link in a new window/tab?

Comment: I totally agree with @JonH, it's annoying for a user to be redirected to the privacy policy when they're about to ask a question (loosing what they've written so far). I'm tweaking it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this :) when we changed the modal library, we had to tweak the way we were including links not meant to be opened inside the modal. We missed these two, and that's why they weren't doing anything else other than closing the modal.

This should be fixed and deployed now.